# ambiguous argument 'HEAD^' in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I saw in web many examples how to get changes files during Azure DevOps pipelines in CI
just using simple code

```
$changedFiles = git diff --name-status HEAD HEAD^
```

but when I am trying to use this in my yaml pipeline I have an error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

what could I do wrong?

Comment: You have a repository that has just one commit, probably as a result of doing a shallow clone, probably as a result of accepting some default. Fix that setting or run `git fetch --unshallow`.

Comment: yes, thanks for comment, was problem with shallow fetch

Answer (score 6):

It seems that I found the issue

Due to this
[image]

I have to follow manual here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#shallow-fetch

Comment: Hi @Alexander, what was your change for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix: disable shallow-fetch. It is enabled by default. Follow the steps presented here using ADO UI -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#shallow-fetch

or in the checkout step specify:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
```